# Why does this proof for quotient rule of limits not work?

Tags: calculus, limits

By doubt is, if we prove the product rule of limits,can't we directly prove the quotient rule ? But wherever I look on the internet, they give another $\epsilon-\delta$  proof for the quotient rule, why is that required ? 
My proof of the quotient rule :

$\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$ = $\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)}$$\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{1}{g(x)}}$ .  (Accepting the product rule)

= $\frac{\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)}}{\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}}$ $\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{1}{g(x)}}$$\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}$    Multiplying and dividing by $\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}$

= $\frac{\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)}}{\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}}$ $\lim_{x\to a}{[\frac{1}{g(x)}}{g(x)} ]$   (Accepting the product rule)

=  $\frac{\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)}}{\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}}$ $\lim_{x\to a}{1}$

= $\frac{\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)}}{\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}}({1})$  (Accepting $\lim_{x\to a}{c}$ = c )

And hence the result. Am I missing something here, maybe this is circular reasoning? Why does this not work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only given that
$$ \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = B \not=0. $$
Without the quotient rule, you don't even know whether
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{g(x)} $$
exists (or that it is equal to $1/B$), so that the use of the product rule in your first step is unjustified.

However, if you prove the statement above, then you can use the product rule to prove the general quotient rule
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{A}{B}, $$
as you proposed.

**EDIT**: Just to be fully clear, here are the statements of the product rule and the quotient rule.

> Suppose that $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = A, \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = B.$$
>   Then
>   $$ \lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot g(x) = A\cdot B. $$
>   If we also have
>   $$ \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = B \not= 0, $$
>   then
>   $$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{A}{B}. $$

Notice that it is nowhere assumed that
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{g(x)} $$
exists. This needs to be proven (which basically amounts to proving the quotient rule).

Comment: If you look closely, I never used $\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{1}{g(x)}} = \frac{1}{\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}} $, directly or indirectly. I only used the product rule througout the proof and the fact that $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ is also a function. I only multiplied- divided by ${\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}} $

Comment: Yes, but in your first step you claim that $$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} f(x) \; \lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{g(x)} $$ by the product rule, which is not necessarily true (given the assumptions and if you only accept the product rule). The product rule requires you to know that the limits of both factors exist. However, as I already stated in my answer, without the quotient rule (or some other means) you cannot know that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{g(x)}$ exists, so the use of the product rule in your first step is unjustified.

Comment: But isn't it assumed that the limits exist ? Like while proving the product rule you assume that the individual limits existed, so why not here ? (Also limit of g(x) is non zero. I should have given that). Where's the flaw in the logic ?

Comment: @Steve Again, you only assume that $ \lim g(x) $ exists. At this point you do not yet know whether this implies that $\lim 1/g(x)$ exists as well (this implication is proven true using the chain rule).

Comment: @Steve That being said, you could of course assume that $\lim 1/g(x)$ exists, but this is a superfluous condition, since the fact that $\lim g(x)$ exists implies that $\lim 1/g(x)$ exists as well, but you basically need to prove the quotient rule prove this implication.

Comment: @Steve I hope my edit clarifies the matter.

Comment: Chain rule ? What's that ?

Comment: @Steve Oh, my bad. I meant the quotient rule, of course. You will learn about the chain rule once you start with derivatives, but this is unrelated to this question. :)

Comment: I know the chain rule, i was asking why use it here :) . Anyways, I now understand that the seemingly faultless proof assumes the rule itself (existence of lim(1/g(x)) should be proven first if lim(G(x)) exists and we have to assume the quotient rule to be true for that). Thanks.

Comment: @Steve Indeed! Glad I could help.